# Удаление картинок из кеша google

Tags: php, кэширование

Сайт содержит миллионы картинок, значительная часть из них была удалена, но продолжает появляться по запросу в поисковике. Есть ли способ удалить эти картинки, возможно с помощью API? Нашел вариант удаления через webmasters tool, путем добавления url'ов, по которым находится картинка для удаления, но такой вариант не подходит, потому что картинок очень много.

Answer (score 2):

Тут подробно все варианты расписаны — [Как удалить изображение из результатов поиска](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4628134?hl=ru) и далее тут [«Как удалить контент навсегда»](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419#make-permanent).

Или через robots.txt — [Запрет на показ изображений с вашего сайта в результатах поиска Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=ru).

Какой вариант удобнее зависит от ситуации: какие пути у этих картинок, как настроен веб-сервер на их отдачу и т.п.

**Важное примечение**

А вы точно хотите их удалить раз их миллионы? **Трафик к вам на сайт идет?** Если да — то это органический трафик! А вы его «убить» хотите. **Выводите на своем сайте, что данный ресурс удален** и возвращайте [410 код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#410). И пользователь возможно останется у вас на сайте и продолжит искать, что ему нужно.

Также по возможности лучше перенаправить пользователя (сделать редирект) на ту страницу (карточку товара, например) с которой были связаны те или иные картинки (да, пусть это и были картинки, но перенаправить на страницу с [кодом 301](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#301)). Или вернуть 410 код для данного ресурса, отображить страницу, например, с шапкой, написать, что страница/ресурс удален и дать ссылку на связанный или тот же товар/страницу, например.

Вообщем я бы в эту сторону думал.

**P.S.:** Если у вас на веб-сервере статика раздается через NGINX — возможно понадобятся дополнительные настройки. Но раз трафик идет с картинок — я бы постарался максимально им воспользоваться.

Comment: "А вы точно хотите их удалить раз их миллионы?" - Да, потому что нарушаются авторские права

Comment: И я уже написал, что ваш вариант мне не подходит, потому что картинок очень много. Думаете хорошим вариантом будет прописывать каждый юрл вручную?

Comment: @maxim-kravetc я вам привел варианты решения. Прописывать каждую по отдельности или задавать шаблон... и я же написал — «...какие пути у этих картинок, как настроен веб-сервер на их отдачу и т.п.».

Я же не знаю, что у вас происходит при переходе на картинку, которую вы физически удалили с сервера. Если они удалены с сервера — дальше вопрос времени — гугл скорее сам всё удалил, если веб-сервер и сайт настроен правильно.

То есть со своей стороны вы проблему решили путем удаления картинок с сервера, а дальше как я понимаю правообладатели пускай сами решают с Google.

Comment: Если у вас все картинки начинаются с пути, например, /images/13123123.jpg то... в robots.txt можно прописать: User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/

Comment: @maxim-kravetc, а новые картинки загружать по пути, например, /img/new.jpg Понимаете к чему я?

Comment: Я понял, но с robots.txt тоже не подойдет, потому что нет определенного шаблона пути к удаленным картинкам. Можно конечно сделать автоматическое добавление пути в robots.txt после удаления, но это не очень вариант

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63075/discussion-between-alexander-bragin-and-maxim-kravetc).